# Why i cant install plugins and themes in my local host?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, installation, themes

All i get is this error page why is that? I am running wamp on windows10.
http://prntscr.com/84fikq

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when WordPress checks for Nonce in an admin url and the check fails. Nonce are unique keys or numbers which can be generated by a theme, plugin, or a core WordPress file for verification purposes. Nonces add a security layer to protect WordPress URLs, forms, and ajax calls from abuse.

‘**Are you sure you want to do this?**’ error usually appears when nonce verification fails and the most likely candidates to cause this error are plugins and themes not using nonce properly.

Make sure the theme and plugins you are using are both known compatible with installed wordpress version. Also try increasing your max_execution_time, your max_input_time, and your memory_limit, via the php.ini. If you do not have a php.ini file, use the PHP Config icon in the cPanel to install one. Also set your php mode to Single php.ini while you are there.

Maybe try something like:

```
memory_limit = 128M 
upload_max_filesize = 80M
post_max_size = 80M
```

Above all values are depending on your file size.

Let me know if there is any concern from this.

Comment: If you are working on local then please restart your server and check because .ini settings may require restart server to load new changes.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/84gog9
Its happening the same i restarted wamp and nothing happened.